# PHP Script - Activity Description not reflecting record values

Tags: php, mysql

I had a need for a system that could track billable tasks for tickets that we processed. I have a script that is almost complete, but I cannot seem to figure out why the tickets_tasks_activity field is not pulling the right enum_short_description when displaying. When I add a task the values are added correctly, its only not displaying them correctly. It seems that I can add one activity... and then every additional activity has the same description even though the values are different in the database. Could someone please help me out.

Here is the script to pull the information from the database.

```
 * Get the tasks associated with a ticket.
 * 
 * @company_id The ID of the company that is being queried.
 * @ticket_id  The ID of the ticket that is being queried.
 */
function get_ticket_tasks($company_id, $ticket_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT u.user_first_name,
                   u.user_last_name,
                   u.user_id,
                   tn.tickets_tasks_posted_date,
                   tn.tickets_tasks_task,
                   tn.tickets_tasks_activity,
                   (SELECT enum_short_description FROM tbl_enum WHERE enum_id = tn.tickets_tasks_activity) tickets_tasks_activity_description
              FROM tbl_tickets_tasks tn,
                   tbl_user u
            WHERE tn.tickets_tasks_company_id = {$company_id}
              AND tn.tickets_tasks_ticket_id = {$ticket_id}
              AND tn.tickets_tasks_posted_user_id = u.user_id;";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    // If nothing was returned invalid query.
    if($query->num_rows() == 0)
        return false;

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Here is the code for the View Page

```
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tasks">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <?php
                    if($tasks)
                    { ?>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Service Provided</th>
                                    <th>Value</th>
                                    <th>Who?</th>
                                    <th>When?</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                for($i = 0; $i < count($tasks); ++$i)
                                { ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $tasks[0]['tickets_tasks_activity_description']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo nl2br($tasks[$i]['tickets_tasks_task']); ?></td>
                                        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/view/<?php echo $tasks[$i]['user_id']; ?>"><?php echo $tasks[$i]['user_first_name'].' '.$tasks[$i]['user_last_name']; ?></a></td>
                                        <td><?php echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($tasks[$i]['tickets_tasks_posted_date'])); ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php
                                } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    <?php
                    }
                    else
                    { ?>
                        <p>This ticket does not have any tasks.</p>
                    <?php
                    } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have (at the beginning of the loop):

`<td><?php echo $tasks[0]['tickets_tasks_activity_description']; ?></td>`

you're printing always *$task[**0**]*, you should print *$task[**$i**]*

PS: You should probably state your JOIN in the FROM section of your SQL clause (instead to put it on the WERE section), at first I though you had none :-)